# To run python script when my Amazon instance boots up

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ami

Where should i place my script in amazon instance such that my script should run when my instance boots up?

I tried placing it in rc.local but it didnt help.

My script is about connecting to Amazon S3, uploading some docs & downloading some docs.
I have written my script in python and placed it inside a .sh file.

Comment: What's the content of the first line of your `.sh` file?

Answer (score 4):

Scripts from rc.local should run just fine on boot. You may just have a bug in your script. You could try adding logging to your script in the rc.local like such:

```
/path/to/myscripts/myscript.sh > /var/log/log.txt 2>&1
```

Then boot up and check the log for any errors. One usual suspect is not using absolute paths in the scripts so that might be worth a check.